# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm new to the Oracle PL/SQL and I'm getting error mentioned in the title, exactly at line **30**, when I try to run this code in Oracle APEX.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE enter_student_grade 
    (p_num_grade IN class_assessments.numeric_grade%TYPE, 
     p_class_assessment_id IN class_assessments.class_assessment_id%TYPE,
     p_class_id IN class_assessments.class_id%TYPE,
     p_stu_id IN class_assessments.stu_id%TYPE, 
     p_assessment_id class_assessments.assessment_id%TYPE,
     p_date_turned_in IN DATE := SYSDATE) IS

v_max_id class_assessments.class_assessment_id%TYPE := 0;
v_max_attempts NUMBER(1,0):= 0;
BEGIN


    SELECT max(class_assessment_id)+1 INTO v_max_id
    FROM class_assessments;

    SELECT count(stu_id) INTO v_max_attempts FROM class_assessments WHERE stu_id = p_stu_id AND assessment_id = p_assessment_id

    IF  v_max_attempts < 3 THEN 

        INSERT INTO class_assessments
        (class_assessment_id,date_turned_id,numeric_grade,letter_grade,class_id,stu_id,assessment_id)
        VALUES
        (v_max_id,p_date_turned_in,p_num_grade,convert_grade(p_num_grade),p_class_id,p_stu_id,p_assessment_id);
        commit;
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('ERROR: Current student has reached maximum number of attempts for this assessment');
    END IF;

END enter_student_grade;
```

I have no idea, where can be the source of this error. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbol `;` is missing after second SELECT statement (before IF).

Comment: Oh, such a stupid mistake. Thank You. I should definitely get some sleep :) Problem solved